# PYTHONPATH storage location

Tags: python, pythonpath

Where is my pythonpath stored? 
When I write

```
import sys
sys.path
```

Where does Python get that data?

Comment: any reason you want to know where it is stored? If you want python to use a different pythonpath, you could set the environment variable: PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python gets that data from the path attribute of the `sys` module. This path is a `list`, and if you want to add a new directory to the path, just use the `append` method.

For instance, to add the directory `/home/me/mypy` to the path, just do:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/me/mypy")
```